# wxPython adding/removing controls during runtime to ScrolledWindow

Tags: python, python-3.x, wxpython

I'm trying to add/remove multiple items to a [ScrolledWindow](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.ScrolledWindow.html) in [wxPython](https://wxpython.org/).
At the moment I have the following control architecture:
[image: Imgur]

I want to add multiple instances of the `resultItem_panel` to the `result_scrolledWindow`.
When I do so I first have to scale the window manually by dragging it with the cursor for it to update and the `result_scrolledWindow` to show the scroll bars.
My code at the moment:

```py
def __addPublication(self, pub: Publication) -> None:
    resultItem_panel = ResultItemPanel(self, pub)

    # Add to parent sizer:
    self.result_sizer.Add(resultItem_panel, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
    self.Layout()
    self.Parent.Fit()

    # Store it so we later can Destroy() it again:
    self.resultItemPanels.append(resultItem_panel)

def clearPublications(self) -> None:
    for pub in self.resultItemPanels:
        pub.Destroy()
    self.resultItemPanels = []

    self.Layout()
    self.Parent.Fit()
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing:

```py
self.Layout()
self.Parent.Fit()
```

with:

```py
self.result_sizer.Layout()
self.PostSizeEvent()
```

did the trick for me.
Reference: [Phoenix (wxPython) #1221](https://github.com/wxWidgets/Phoenix/issues/1221)